# Why django creates new default permissions even with default_permissions=() in the Meta?

Tags: django

I setup some test app to check django's behaviour.

Makefile for testing:

```
clean:
    rm db.sqlite3

mig_model:
    python manage.py migrate flights 0001

mig_all:
    python manage.py migrate

show1 show2:
    python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission; print(list(Permission.objects.values_list('id', 'codename')))"

all: clean mig_model show1 mig_all show2
```

- removing old db
- migrating to the point when first own model is created
- after migration default permissions should be created in post_migrate signal. But I specify in Model.Meta that no default permissions should be created
- check all permissions - I can see that they were indeed generated
- migrate everything else, which is just 1 more data-migration where I delete all permissions in the system
- show all permissions again and I can see that old permission were deleted and new ones created after migration (they all have new ids)

models.py:

```
class Schedule(models.Model):
    flight_day = models.DateField()

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ()
        permissions = ()
```

output of `make all`

```
.venv ❯ make all
rm db.sqlite3
python manage.py migrate flights 0001
Operations to perform:
  Target specific migration: 0001_initial, from flights
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial... OK
  Applying auth.0001_initial... OK
  Applying contenttypes.0002_remove_content_type_name... OK
  Applying auth.0002_alter_permission_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0003_alter_user_email_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0004_alter_user_username_opts... OK
  Applying auth.0005_alter_user_last_login_null... OK
  Applying auth.0006_require_contenttypes_0002... OK
  Applying auth.0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages... OK
  Applying auth.0008_alter_user_username_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0010_alter_group_name_max_length... OK
  Applying auth.0011_update_proxy_permissions... OK
  Applying flights.0001_initial... OK
python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission; print(list(Permission.objects.values_list('id', 'codename')))"
[(5, 'add_group'), (6, 'change_group'), (7, 'delete_group'), (8, 'view_group'), (1, 'add_permission'), (2, 'change_permission'), (3, 'delete_permission'), (4, 'view_permission'), (9, 'add_user'), (10, 'change_user'), (11, 'delete_user'), (12, 'view_user'), (13, 'add_contenttype'), (14, 'change_contenttype'), (15, 'delete_contenttype'), (16, 'view_contenttype'), (17, 'add_schedule'), (18, 'change_schedule'), (19, 'delete_schedule'), (20, 'view_schedule'), (21, 'add_scheduleperf'), (22, 'change_scheduleperf'), (23, 'delete_scheduleperf'), (24, 'view_scheduleperf')]
python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, flights, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying admin.0001_initial... OK
  Applying admin.0002_logentry_remove_auto_add... OK
  Applying admin.0003_logentry_add_action_flag_choices... OK
  Applying flights.0002_delete_perms...DELETE ALL (24, {'auth.Group_permissions': 0, 'auth.User_user_permissions': 0, 'auth.Permission': 24})
 OK
  Applying sessions.0001_initial... OK
python manage.py shell -c "from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission; print(list(Permission.objects.values_list('id', 'codename')))"
[(25, 'add_logentry'), (26, 'change_logentry'), (27, 'delete_logentry'), (28, 'view_logentry'), (33, 'add_group'), (34, 'change_group'), (35, 'delete_group'), (36, 'view_group'), (29, 'add_permission'), (30, 'change_permission'), (31, 'delete_permission'), (32, 'view_permission'), (37, 'add_user'), (38, 'change_user'), (39, 'delete_user'), (40, 'view_user'), (41, 'add_contenttype'), (42, 'change_contenttype'), (43, 'delete_contenttype'), (44, 'view_contenttype'), (49, 'add_schedule'), (50, 'change_schedule'), (51, 'delete_schedule'), (52, 'view_schedule'), (53, 'add_scheduleperf'), (54, 'change_scheduleperf'), (55, 'delete_scheduleperf'), (56, 'view_scheduleperf'), (45, 'add_session'), (46, 'change_session'), (47, 'delete_session'), (48, 'view_session')]
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django Docs:

> These permissions will be created when you run manage.py migrate; the
>   first time you run migrate after adding django.contrib.auth to
>   INSTALLED_APPS, the default permissions will be created for all
>   previously-installed models, as well as for any new models being
>   installed at that time. Afterward, it will create default permissions
>   for new models each time you run manage.py migrate (the function that
>   creates permissions is connected to the post_migrate signal).

The code:

```
default_permissions = ()
```

Does not prevent this from happening.

If I know more of what you're trying to do I might be able to help better.